# Events overlap on chronology with chronosys

Tags: chronology

I'm trying to use the `chronosys` package and unfortunately the events are overlaping each other.

Here is a minimal example :

```
\documentclass[article]
\usepackage{chronosys}
\begin{document}
\startchronology
  \chronoevent{1500}{Texte A}
  \chronoevent{1525}{Texte B}
\stopchronology
\end{document}
```

And here is the result :
[image: Overlaping events]

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156878/timeline-in-beamer-presentation/156883#156883.  If `chronosys` is forcing your "year-line" to be linear, that could be a problem with closely spaced dates.  The alternate approach cited here allows you to tailor the inter-year separations to suit.  The appearance could be made to look more like what you have in your question, as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
\documentclass[article]
\usepackage{chronosys}
\begin{document}
\startchronology
\chronoevent[markdepth=60pt]{1525}{Texte B}%order - furthest out first
\chronoevent{1500}{Texte A}
\stopchronology
\end{document}
```

[image]