# Use timeline library with months

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to adapt this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183049/9953) to a timeline that has months instead of years. The first part of the MWE below is just the [timeline library](https://github.com/cfiandra/timeline).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
% Timeline library
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc}
\usepackage{xstring}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  timespan/.store in=\timespan,
  timespan=Week,
  timeline width/.store in=\timelinewidth,
  timeline width=20,
  timeline height/.store in=\timelineheight,
  timeline height=1,
  timeline offset/.store in=\timelineoffset,
  timeline offset=0.15,
  initial week/.store in=\initialweek,
  initial week=1,
  end week/.store in=\endweek,
  end week=2,
  time point/.store in=\timepoint,
  time point=0.5,
  between week/.style args={#1 and #2 in #3}{
    initial week=#1,
    end week=#2,
    time point=#3,
  },
  involvement degree/.store in=\involvdegree,
  involvement degree=2cm,
  phase color/.store in=\phasecol,
  phase color=red!50!orange,
  phase appearance/.style={
    circle,
    opacity=0.3,
    minimum size=\involvdegree,
    fill=\phasecol
  },
}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/milestone/.cd,
  at/.store in=\msstartpoint,
  at=phase-1.north,
  circle radius/.store in=\milestonecircleradius,
  circle radius=0.1cm,
  direction/.store in=\msdirection,
  direction=90:2cm,
  text/.store in=\mstext,
  text={},
  text options/.code={\tikzset{#1}},
}

\newcommand{\reftimespan}{\MakeLowerCase{\timespan}}

\newcommand{\timeline}[1]{
  \draw[fill,opacity=0.8] (0,0) rectangle (\timelinewidth,\timelineheight);
  \shade[top color=black, bottom color=white,middle color=black!20]
    (0,0) rectangle (\timelinewidth,-\timelineoffset);
  \shade[top color=white, bottom color=black,middle color=black!20]
    (0,\timelineheight) rectangle (\timelinewidth,\timelineheight+\timelineoffset);

  \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {1,...,#1} {\global\let\maxsmitem\xi}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\position{\timelinewidth/(\maxsmitem+1)}
  \node at (0,0.5\timelineheight)(\timespan-0){\phantom{Week 0}};

  \foreach \x[count=\xi] in {1,...,#1}{
      \node[text=white]at +(\xi*\position,0.5\timelineheight) (\timespan-\xi) {\timespan\ \x};
  }
}

\newcounter{involv}
\setcounter{involv}{0}

\newcommand{\phase}[1]{
\stepcounter{involv}
\node[phase appearance,#1]
(phase-\theinvolv)
at ($(\timespan-\initialweek)!\timepoint!(\timespan-\endweek)$){};
}

\newcommand{\initialphase}[1]{
\node[phase appearance,#1,anchor=west,between week=0 and 1 in 0,]
(phase-\theinvolv)
at ($(\timespan-0)!0!(\timespan-1)$){};
\setcounter{involv}{0}
}

\newenvironment{phases}{\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}}{\end{pgfonlayer}}

\newcommand{\addmilestone}[1]{
\pgfkeys{/tikz/milestone/.cd,#1}
\draw[double,fill] (\msstartpoint) circle [radius=\milestonecircleradius];
\draw(\msstartpoint)--++(\msdirection)node[/tikz/milestone/text options]{\mstext};
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% redefinition for having a interval not starting from 1
\renewcommand{\timeline}[1]{
  \draw[fill,opacity=0.8] (0,0) rectangle (\timelinewidth,\timelineheight);
  \shade[top color=black, bottom color=white,middle color=black!20]
    (0,0) rectangle (\timelinewidth,-\timelineoffset);
  \shade[top color=white, bottom color=black,middle color=black!20]
    (0,\timelineheight) rectangle (\timelinewidth,\timelineheight+\timelineoffset);

  \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#1}  {\global\let\maxsmitem\xi}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\position{\timelinewidth/(\maxsmitem+1)}
  \node at (0,0.5\timelineheight)(\timespan-0){\phantom{Week 0}};

  \foreach \x[count=\xi] in {#1}{
      \node[text=white]at +(\xi*\position,0.5\timelineheight) (\timespan-\xi) {\timespan\ \x};
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[timespan={},% empty to not display a label before the month
  between month/.style args={#1 and #2 in #3}{% auxiliary style for month
    initial week=#1,
    end week=#2,
    time point=#3,
  }
  ]
\timeline{August,September, October, November, December, January, February,
  March, April, May, June, July} % months

% put here the phases
\begin{phases}
\phase{between month=1 and 10 in 0.2,involvement degree=4cm}
\phase{between month=3 and 7 in 0.5,phase color=blue!80!cyan}
\end{phases}

% put here the milestones
\addmilestone{at=phase-2.110,direction=120:1.5cm,text={Testing milestone text},text options={above}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Using the updated version of the timeline libray the names of the months in the following MWE are wrongly aligned and too close one to another. The other thing that I would like to achieve is to say something like

```
\phase{between week=1 and 7 in 0.5,involvement degree=4cm}
```

and have the phase (bubble) cover the whole distance between the starting and endpoints.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\input{timeline_library.tex}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[timespan={}]

\timeline[custom interval=true]{August, September, October, November, December,
  January, February, March, April, May, June, July}

\begin{phases}
\initialphase{involvement degree=1.75cm,phase color=black}
\phase{between week=1 and 7 in 0.5,involvement degree=4cm}
\end{phases}

\addmilestone{at=phase-0.90,direction=90:1cm,text={Initial meeting},text options={above}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you check out the latest version of the library posted 16 hours ago? https://github.com/cfiandra/timeline

Comment: See the file `example.tex` for an illustration of the new facilities which allow you to specify months or years... By the way, did you have a question?

Comment: @cfr I do have a question. See my comment to the answer below.

Comment: @crf I've have edited the question to convey properly what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The new version of the library can use custom time intervals. As a result, it is now possible to set up a timeline with the names of the months:

```
\timeline[custom interval=true]{January, March, May, July, September, November}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{timeline}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[timespan={}]% no label is displayed for the timespan

\timeline[custom interval=true]{January, March, May, July, September, November}

% put here the phases
\begin{phases}
\initialphase{involvement degree=1.75cm,phase color=black}
\phase{between week=1 and 2 in 0.1,involvement degree=2.25cm}
\phase{between week=1 and 2 in 0.5,involvement degree=3cm}
\phase{between week=1 and 2 in 0.9,involvement degree=2.125cm}
\phase{between week=3 and 4 in 0.7,phase color=blue!80!cyan}
\end{phases}

% put here the milestones
\addmilestone{at=phase-0.90,direction=90:1cm,text={Initial meeting},text options={above}}
\addmilestone{at=phase-0.270,direction=270:1cm,text={Initial meeting},text options={below}}

\addmilestone{at=phase-2.110,direction=120:1.5cm,text={Research},text options={above}}
\addmilestone{at=phase-2.250,direction=240:1.5cm,text={Need Agreement},text options={below}}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

For what concern the vertical alignment, a `text depth` was missing since the labels were not supposed to be pure text at the beginning. It is fixed in version 0.3a of the library.

For what concern the other point, I will show how to change shape and to use the `between month` option (basically an alias of `between week`): so far it is not possible to draw a rectangle *from month 1 to month 7*, but one has to play with the key `involvement degree` to find the correct setting. Why? Very simple. To a TikZ node you can only specify the minimum width and nodes are needed to be able to deploy milestones. To have nodes' width to be of a given width, one has to measure things and at the moment I don't have time to implement this feature. It is a nice suggestion, though, so it will be implemented in the near future.

The code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{timeline}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[timespan={},timeline width=25]

\timeline[custom interval=true]{August, September, October, November, December,
  January, February, March, April, May, June, July}

% put here the phases
\begin{phases}
\initialphase{involvement degree=1.75cm,phase color=black}
\tikzset{phase appearance/.append style={
  rectangle, 
  minimum width=\involvdegree,
  minimum height=3cm}
}
\phase{between month=1 and 7 in 0.5,phase color=green!80!black,involvement degree=12cm}
\end{phases}

% put here the milestones
\addmilestone{at=phase-0.90,direction=90:1cm,text={Initial meeting},text options={above}}
\addmilestone{at=phase-0.270,direction=270:1cm,text={Initial meeting},text options={below}}
\addmilestone{at=phase-1.270,direction=270:1cm,text={A big achievement},text options={below}}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering it is possible to say something like `\phase{between week=1 and 4,involvement degree=3cm}` and have the phase bubble cover the the timeline from January to July. With the current settings the bubble is place at a certain position between the points. I don't want that. I would like the bubble (or another shape, maybe a rectangle) to go from the starting position to the end position.

Comment: @petobens: please, see my updated answer. BTW: I would suggest to use `\usetikzlibrary{timeline}` rather than `\input{timeline_libary.tex}`, whose content is a mistery (at least to me).

Comment: Thanks. It works great now. I saved the timeline library in `timeline_library.tex` and then used the `\input` command in my preamble. Your way is probably better.