# How to create a timeline with references instead of dates?

Tags: timeline

I would like to insert a timeline into my thesis and replace dates by references to the lines of an interview such as : (l. 5-25) (l. is for line). I found an example of timeline that is quite what I'm looking for. But how can I replace years by references ? This is below that mwe I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274589/creating-a-timeline) :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chronosys}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}


\startchronology[startyear=-3000,stopyear=-2000, startdate=false, color=blue!40, stopdate=false, arrow=true, height=3pt]
\setupchronoevent{textstyle=\scriptsize,datestyle=\scriptsize}
\chronograduation[event]{100}
\chronoevent[markdepth=60pt]{-2080}{IM15 (C)}
\chronoevent[markdepth=-80pt]{-2115}{IM13 (C)}
\chronoevent[markdepth=20pt]{-2115}{IM26 (B)}
\chronoevent[markdepth=100pt]{-2170}{IM20 (B)} 
\chronoevent[markdepth=-120pt]{-2190}{IIIM76 (E)}
\chronoevent[markdepth=70pt]{-2200}{IIIM353 (C)}
\chronoevent[markdepth=30pt]{-2245}{IIM69 (C)}
\chronoevent[markdepth=-70pt]{-2250}{IIM281 (C)}
\chronoevent[markdepth=-50pt]{-2145}{IM10 (B)}
\chronoevent[markdepth=-30pt]{-2240}{IIM163 (C)}
\chronoevent[markdepth=-70pt]{-2475}{IM90 (C)}
\chronoevent[markdepth=20pt]{-2480}{IM90 (B)}
\chronoevent[markdepth=-20pt]{-2500}{IIM63 (C)}
\chronoevent[markdepth=70pt]{-2550}{IM21 (A)}
\chronoevent[markdepth=-50pt]{-2570}{IM163 (B)}
\chronoevent[markdepth=30pt]{-2620}{IIM13 (C)}
\chronoevent[markdepth=-40pt]{-2690}{IM5 (B)}
\chronoevent[markdepth=40pt]{-2760}{IM130 (B)}
\chronoevent[markdepth=-15pt]{-2770}{IM65 (C)}
\chronoevent{-2935}{IM157 (B)}
\stopchronology
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: maybe this post could help you : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183046/how-do-i-develop-a-complex-time-line/227149#227149

Comment: I just found this example and it would be perfect if only I could use it. It's a vertical timeline : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52394/high-level-macros-and-environments-based-on-tikz/154558#154558

Comment: In what sense is it a timeline exactly? This would make more sense to me if you wanted to use, say, seconds or minutes into an interview: then it would be time. But how does time relate to `lines` of the interview exactly?

Comment: @cfr It is not exactly a timeline since I refer to words and lines. I would like to show something like an alternating between some sections of a discourse and, in this case, the principle of a timeline is appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want here is not really a timeline as such. But maybe something like the following could be the basis for a solution.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\newlength\interviewunit
\tikzset{%
  interview line/.code={%
    \tikzset{interview/.cd, #1}
    \pgfmathsetlength\interviewunit{(\interviewtotht-10mm)/\interviewlines}
    \draw [interview/line] (0,5mm) coordinate (interview start) -- +(0,{-\interviewtotht-5mm}) coordinate (interview end);
  },
  interview/.search also={/tikz},
  interview/.cd,
  total height/.store in=\interviewtotht,
  total height=100mm,
  lines/.store in=\interviewlines,
  lines=100,
  line/.style={thick, gray, {Circle}-{Latex}},
  mark/.style={gray,fill},
}
\newcommand*\interviewmarker[3][0pt]{%
  \draw [interview/mark] (0,{-\interviewunit*#2}) circle (1.5pt) -- +(35mm,#1) circle (1.5pt) coordinate (interview mark);
  \node [right=2.5mm of interview mark, anchor=west, align=left]  {l.~#2: #3};
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    interview line,
  ]
  \interviewmarker{34}{Take a break!}
  \interviewmarker{0}{Start}
  \interviewmarker[-10pt]{1}{Meet \& greet.}
  \interviewmarker{75}{Phone rings.}
  \interviewmarker{100}{End}
  \interviewmarker{64}{Switch on lights.}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: interview line]

Comment: This mwe is nearly what I am looking for. I need to have a "timeline" that begins at line 1 and ends to line 58. Between those two points, I have several lines to mark : l. 1-10, l. 11-28, and so on.

Comment: `lines=100` is just an example. Use `lines=58` if you have 58 lines. Similarly, change `100mm` if you want a taller or shorter diagram. I don't know how a range should look as the examples you linked/posted don't seem to cover it. (Other timeline examples do, but tend to look a bit different.)