# Making a timeline in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am working on my thesis and I would like to make a simple "technology timeline", probably something like this (although I prefer horizontal timelines):

[image]

- Are there useful packages that I can use?
- Do you prefer Tikz or PSTricks for such a job?

Comment: hello, that a look on : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183046/how-do-i-develop-a-complex-time-line/227149#227149

Comment: or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215082/1952

Comment: Why do they all get up so early and what on Earth do they have to do with the development of technology? Did Kant invent TEDs or something? (Transcendence Emitting Diodes.)