# tikz: create a time-summary arrow with text

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have a doubt on the following request: I would like to obtain something like the picture attached.
[image]

I tried a sort of "for" loop strategy, but it did not work. here is the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-3.5,0) -- (3.5,0) node [below] {};
    \foreach \x in {-1,...,2}
    \draw (\x, 0.1) -- (\x, -0.1) node [below] {\x};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, I do not understand how integers might be replaced by dates/years, possibly highlighted by some text below the node (and above some math)..
What's your suggestions?

Thanks in advance for everything

Best

1dre

Comment: Please, add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing what you did so far. It's useful for us to have something to start from (and put in context: it's a static figure? A beamer slide?) and for you to better define your question.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it, so you can understand better my problem :)

Comment: Maybe you could find some inspiration in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183046/how-do-i-develop-a-complex-time-line

Comment: Thanks @wilx! I got lot of inspiration from your comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would name the nodes and then explicitly add the information — especially if the information is not automatically generated. For example, in the following example you have the nodes on your line named `point1` to `point5` and you can do a lot of things with them:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % These are to avoid the problem with 
\usepackage{lmodern}     % missing font shapes
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick, ->] (0,0) -- (6,0) node [below] {};
    \foreach \x in {1,...,5}
    \draw (\x, 0.1) -- node[pos=0.5] (point\x) {} (\x, -0.1);
    % node's content --- access them as point1...point5
    \path (point1) node [below] {Below of 1};
    \path (point1) node [above] {$A=1$};
    \path (point4) node [red, above] {Above 4};
    \draw [blue, ->] (point3) -- ++(0,2) node [above] {and this!};
    \path (point2) edge[green, bend right, <->] (point4);
    % you got the idea... 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

A first solution :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-3.5,0) -- (3.5,0) node [below] {};
    \foreach \x/\d in {-1/1965,0/1980,1/2003,2/2005}
    \draw (\x, 0.1) -- (\x, -0.1) node [below] {\shortstack{\d\\Text}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) You really don't need the libraries for the MWE (and nor did the OP).