# Text hide over Chronosys periode

Tags: timeline, chronosys

I want to move the text of a chronoperiode to the middle of the box, but the text keep behind the box and is not visible. I tried to with tikz boxes too, but it doen't work.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks!

Example code:

```
\begin{chronology}
    \setupchronograduation[event]{}
    \chronograduation{2}
    \chronoperiode[textdepth=-1mm,ifcolorbox=false,dates=false,color=blue]{2005}{2010}{--Text 1--}
    \chronoperiode[textdepth=-1mm,ifcolorbox=false,dates=false,color=green]{2011}{2015}{
        \tikz \node (B) at (0,0) {--Text 2--};
    }
\end{chronology}
```

Comment: please see the answer below

Comment: please see -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184297/197451

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please a fully compilable code.

Comment: Which box? nnmm

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there's not enough information to understand what the OP is trying to do. (Even if I complete and compile the fragment, I can't figure out which box or which text.) And if it hasn't been clarified by now, I assume it won't be.